# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Version' of null in outlook-web-16.01.js

Tags: outlook-addin

```
outlook-web-16.01.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Version' of null
at Object.callback (outlook-web-16.01.js:formatted:4686)
at rt (outlook-web-16.01.js:formatted:4272)
```

This is what I get when I tried to use

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
```

Comment: Are you using it inside a dialog?

Comment: I used it in RHS panel. After overriding everything inside `<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">` problem has solved. I have a another addin. In it I am using "Dialog API" with "ExecuteFunction". I get the same error. But not when I click the close icon, but when I use my buttons which are use `Office.context.ui.MessageParent`.

Comment: @DarkLegend In IE it showing a error popup asking you want to debug or not. So I have to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After overriding everything inside `<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">` problem has solved.

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
...

<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
...

  <WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>9b096de7-56af-4b5c-bab5-360fcdf1b2e2</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:44349/9b096de7-56af-4b5c-bab5-360fcdf1b2e2</Resource>
    <Scopes>
      <Scope>user.read</Scope>
      <Scope>files.read</Scope>
      <Scope>profile</Scope>
    </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the solution was. Please show a diff between the problematic manifest and the solved manifest.

Comment: Can you share us what you changed? I hit the same issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou I don't have access to those resources now. Try putting everything on V1_0 inside V1_1, as in the above snippet.

Comment: @JagathWijesinghe Thanks, I already have tried puting everyting V1_0 to V1_1

Comment: @TaoZhou Any luck ?

Comment: @TaoZhou Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as we can see this is a Microsoft bug and is fixed by switching to "Try the new Outlook".

It appears that the current (legacy) UI is trying to access a method that is available only in the "new" API. The only solution would be to modify Microsoft's Javascript API to add the Version property (and link to your own imported version of this rather than the CDN), or wait until Microsoft completes the switch-over.