# Outlook Web Addin Cannot read property 'Version' of null in outlook-web-16.01.js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to achieve call OneDrive Api from Outlook Web Addin.

I used code below to acquire access token.

```
function initializePane() {
    // First attempt to get an SSO token
    if (Office.context.auth !== undefined && Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync !== undefined) {
        Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
            if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                // No need to prompt user, use this token to call Web API
                saveAttachmentsWithSSO(result.value, 1);
            } else if (result.error.code == 13007 || result.error.code == 13005) {
                // These error codes indicate that we need to prompt for consent
                Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ forceConsent: true }, function (result) {
                    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                        saveAttachmentsWithSSO(result.value, 1);
                    } else {
                        // Could not get SSO token, proceed with authentication prompt
                        saveAttachmentsWithPrompt(1);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Could not get SSO token, proceed with authentication prompt
                saveAttachmentsWithPrompt(123);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // SSO not supported
        saveAttachmentsWithPrompt(1);
    }
}
```

The error happened on this line `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Version' of null
>       at Object.callback (outlook-web-16.01.js:16)
>       at rt (outlook-web-16.01.js:16)
>   (anonymous) @   outlook-web-16.01.js:16
>   rt  @   outlook-web-16.01.js:16

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641465/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-version-of-null-in-outlook-web-16-01 seems like a similar issue. Can you look at this once and see if it helps.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The link does not work, it did not share us the difference between worked and nonworked manifest. Could you share me how to change based on the answer?

Comment: Which platform are you using: old-OWA or new-OWA (option which appears on right hand corner: Try the new outlook)?